# kernel compilation: generate modules.dep and map files

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am compiling linux kernel on Debian Stretch:

```
cd linux-4.9.59/
make menuconfig
make
```

so far so good.

normally, I would then issue `make modules_install`, to copy the modules to `/lib/modules/`.

But this kernel is intended for another machine, so I don't want to copy the modules locally. Besides, I am not compiling as root, so writing to `/lib/modules/` would not work anyway.

```
export INSTALL_MOD_PATH="../MY_NEW_KERNEL"
mkdir -vp "${INSTALL_MOD_PATH}

make modules_install
```

The above copies the newly compiled modules to directory `../MY_NEW_KERNEL/lib/modules/`. But it does not generate the modules.dep and map files in `../MY_NEW_KERNEL/lib/modules/`

Normally, if this was currently running kernel, I could run `depmod` to generate it in `/lib/modules/`. But I am not running this kernel on current machine.

And even when I copy bzImage and modules to the target machine, I would have to restart into the new kernel first, and then run `depmod` .

But the problem is, the kernel will not boot because it cannot find the modules, because I did not run `depmod`.

**How can I run `depmod` for kernel modules, when the kernel is not currently running ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, this should work. The System.map was created in the just-built source directory and is required:

```
$ depmod -b "$INSTALL_MOD_PATH" -F System.map 4.9.59
```

Where 4.9.59 is your new non-running kernel's version.

Now,  even the plain vanilla linux kernel source allows to build debian packages.

```
$ make help|grep deb
  deb-pkg             - Build both source and binary deb kernel packages
  bindeb-pkg          - Build only the binary kernel deb package
```

e,g: Instead of `make` and `make modules_install` (as normal user, root isn't needed):

```
stretch-amd64:~/linux-source-4.13.10$ make bindeb-pkg -j4
```

[... way later ...]

```
stretch-amd64:~/linux-source-4.13.10$ $ ls -1 ../*4.13.10*deb
../linux-headers-4.13.10_4.13.10-1_amd64.deb
../linux-image-4.13.10_4.13.10-1_amd64.deb
../linux-libc-dev_4.13.10-1_amd64.deb
```

Of course this might require a few additional debian packages, like `dpkg-dev`, `fakeroot` and a few related, but if the destination is a debian too, that's then perhaps easier to install it there.